# Detect where the application was downloaded

Tags: .net, vb.net, detect

I'm a designer vb Net applications, all my projects are free and gratuitous and put to public download from my website.

The main problem is that many people download them from my website and then uploading them to another host in order to spread with different links and copy part of my job.
The question is, is there any way to detect where the application was downloaded?

This could disable applications that come from other pages and also display a message about visiting the official site.

I remember seeing an application to that, but I have no idea how.
If there is a better method than that, please mention that I do more research on the subject.

*Thank you for your contributions.*

VisualStudio 2010 .NET

Answer (score 1):

I think that you won't be able to know the download location.
You need to see below

1. > **IF** the link of download from your website was put directly to your application

   in order to prevent that happen. You should change the link with not
   directly download but was pass through some GET or POST (if in PHP)
2. > This could disable applications that come from other pages and also
   >   display a message about visiting the official site.

   Since your application is free. I think you would need to put an ads screen (on the first installation or loading - in VBNet called Splash Screen *if not wrong* for the loading).
   And said that in order to support your work, please visit the official website

I don't think so you could find any program that can help u to detect where it was downloaded. Due that there aren't any code running by your application when the download was being processed. Except the website or person who copy your project and upload on their site do the coding to tell you that your application was being downloaded from their site.
All you can do and the simple way was post an ads screen (telling visit your official site) when setup or loading to application.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll be very present place display ads. regards!

Comment: Kindly tick it if you think this is the suitable answer for your question.. Thanks :)